# Adding user to role in mysql using SQL statement

Tags: user-controls, mysql

I need to know if it is possible to **add USER** to ROLE in MYSQL ***using some SQL statement***?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

MySQL doesn't have roles per se.  You can create a new user with basic SELECT permissions like this:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'host' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO 'user'@'host';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

MySQL GRANT docs:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Answer (score 2):

[YES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/adding-users.html) ,

> As an alternative to GRANT, you can
>   create the same accounts directly by
>   issuing INSERT statements and then
>   telling the server to reload the grant
>   tables:

```
shell> mysql --user=root mysql
mysql> INSERT INTO user
    ->     VALUES('localhost','monty',PASSWORD('some_pass'),
    ->     'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y');
mysql> INSERT INTO user
    ->     VALUES('%','monty',PASSWORD('some_pass'),
    ->     'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y');
mysql> INSERT INTO user SET Host='localhost',User='admin',
    ->     Reload_priv='Y', Process_priv='Y';
mysql> INSERT INTO user (Host,User,Password)
    ->     VALUES('localhost','dummy','');
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```